# Fortran compilation error : (USE statement but is not publicly accessible from this module)

Tags: fortran, aix

While doing make , i am getting the error like

```
"Identifier swan_vv2 appeared in a USE statement but is not publicly accessible from this module."
```

```
         USE Couple2Swan,  ONLY : ADCIRC_ETA2 => SWAN_ETA2,
     &                       ADCIRC_UU2 => SWAN_UU2,
     &                       ADCIRC_VV2 => SWAN_VV2,
     &                       ADCIRC_WX2 => SWAN_WX2,
     &                       ADCIRC_WY2 => SWAN_WY2,
     &                       COUPCUR, COUPWIND, COUPWLV,
     &                       InterpoWeight
!Casey 091216: Added these variables for coupling ADCIRC Manning's n values
!              as Madsen friction lengths.
     &                      ,ADCIRC_Z0 => SWAN_Z0,
     &                       COUPFRIC
```

the USE statement consist "ONLY", but after removing ONLY, it says ONLY is necessary.

Can someone help on this.

Regards-
-makrand

adding content of module file :

```
REAL(SZ),ALLOCATABLE :: SWAN_UU2(:,:)
  IF(.NOT.ALLOCATED(SWAN_UU2))  ALLOCATE(SWAN_UU2(1:NP,1:2))
     SWAN_UU2 (IN,1) = 0.D0
     SWAN_UU2 (IN,2) = 0.D0
     SWAN_UU2 (IN,1) = SWAN_UU2 (IN,2)
        SWAN_UU2 (IN,2) = UU2 (IN)
        SWAN_UU2 (IN,2) = 0.D0
  IF(ALLOCATED(SWAN_UU2))  DEALLOCATE(SWAN_UU2)
```

- it is not whole module file, it is some content have the name shown in error, and it is not swan_VV2 in the use statement versus swan_UU2.
- can i upload the module file ?

Comment: The module snippet looks very strange. The executable code is irrelevant, and you cartainly did not show all important declarations. Also, `only` is certainly not necessary for renaming.

Comment: Is it `swan_VV2` in the `use` statement versus `swan_UU2` in the module?   A spelling error?

Answer (score 1):

The `ONLY` statement is required if you only want to include certain subroutines/functions/variables from that module. You can include the whole module using just:

```
USE Couple2Swan
```

The `=>` syntax allows you to "rename" module procedures...

To your question:
From the error message I read that you don't have the requested subroutine/function/variable `SWAN_VV2` in the module `Couple2Swan`. Maybe you misspelled that, or the element is private.